# Why does my bottle server work start with the command python, but not python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

Here is my code for my `server.py` file, taken from Bottle's documentation.

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I try to execute this in the terminal, it works when I do

```
python server.py
```

But when I execute

```
python3 server.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bottle import route, run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'
```

Comment: `python3` is a different interpreter with a different `site-packages`. Try `python3 -m pip install bottle`

Comment: Because you have installed bottle for python2.7 and not for python3, install it for python3 via `pip3.x install bottle`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've installed Bottle into your Python 2 environment, but not your Python 3 environment. (They are distinct; installing a package in one does not make it available in the other.)

Try `pip3 install bottle` or `python3 -m pip install bottle` and see if that resolves the error.